# I have two query And i want to get result form both

Tags: mysql

I have two query And i want to get result form tbl_users_new_rides where findride category
ride_From data and ride_to from equal to pool_ride_type='offerride' ride_from and ride_to
value. below is two query can i mrge these query according requirment .
Thanks for help

```
select ride_from,ride_to from tbl_users_new_rides where pool_ride_type='findride'
select ride_from,ride_to from tbl_users_new_rides where pool_ride_type='offerride'
```

Comment: What about `where pool_ride_type='findride' or  pool_ride_type='offerride'` ?

Comment: you can use OR , IN and get result in single query.

Comment: `where pool_ride_type in('findride','offerride')`

Comment: Devsi Odedra @I need to find result if  ride_from and ride_to value of findride category equal to the ride_from and ride_to value of  offerride category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inshort u can use like this to get exact matching results - 
**select ride_from,ride_to from tbl_users_new_rides where pool_ride_type IN ('findride', 'offerride');**

Comment: Priyanka Kumari@i am trying to fetch result if both category offer ride and pool-ride field match

Comment: @newdeveloper plz go through with above query..u wll get matched records only

Comment: Priyanka Kumari@ I want filter data  when in find-ride category select ride_from,ride_to  then all result show

Comment: @newdeveloper I think u want query like this - "SELECT * FROM `tbl_users_new_rides` as t1 LEFT JOIN tbl_users_new_rides as t2 ON t1.ride_from = t2.ride_from AND t1.ride_to = t2.ride_to WHERE t1.category IN ('findride', 'offerride') GROUP by t1.category"    Plz let me know if its ur solution.

Comment: Priyanka Kumari @syhunk835@gmail.com  can you ping me .

Answer (score 0):

I think this is correct
`select ride_from,ride_to from tbl_users_new_rides where pool_ride_type='offerride' or pool_ride_type='findride'`

Comment: Hoàng Đăng@I need to find result if ride_from and ride_to value of findride category equal to the ride_from and ride_to value of offerride category